# Asking user to choose folder on my USB connected Android

Tags: python, tkinter, usb, usb-drive

I am using the following code to enable the user to chose a folder:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
path = askdirectory(title='Select Folder') # shows dialog box and return the path
print(path)
```

However, the 'Browse' window does not display the Android phone connected via USB, although I can see it via windows explorer.

How can this be enabled?

Comment: USB are different from ordinary directory and I don't think there is an built in tkinter option for you. I guess you need to query the serial port or **u**niversal **s**erial **b**us with a 3rd party modul.

Comment: What you could at least try is to set the initial directory to the USB and see if it works.

Comment: Strange why windows explorer can but python browse window cannot....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter filedialog.askdirectory() can't find external drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70154308/tkinter-filedialog-askdirectory-cant-find-external-drives)